# How can I update my node config file using Jenkins environment variables?

Tags: json, shell, jenkins, configuration, devops

I integrated Jenkins with my node project.
While building the project on Jenkins, I want to update my node config variables using Jenkins environment variables.

Here is my template config file.

```
{
  "aws": {
    "s3": {
      "base_url": "AWS_S3_BASE_URL",
      "bucket": "AWS_S3_BUCKET",
      "region": "AWS_S3_REGION",
      "accessKeyId": "AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY",
      "secretAccessKey": "AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
    }
  },
  "db": {
    "sequelize": {
      "dialect": "postgres",
      "logging": true,
      "database": "DB_DATABASE",
      "port": 5432,
      "minConnections": 1,
      "maxConnections": 4,
      "maxIdleTime": 1000,
      "write": {
        "endpoint": "DB_HOST",
        "username": "DB_USER",
        "password": "DB_PASSWORD"
      },
      "read": [
      {
        "endpoint": "DB_HOST",
        "username": "DB_USER",
        "password": "DB_PASSWORD"
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I update these variables using Jenkins environment variables?

Thanks in advance!